# What is the /apps/services/loguploader URL for in a Worklight 6.2 application?

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst

I am debugging a Worklight 6.2-based application. Using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I can see data flowing between the client-side (app) and the server-side (Worklight server), and there are periodically requests which hit a URL of the form `http://myserver.com/myProjectName/apps/services/loguploader`. I assume that this is related to the [Client-side Log Capture facility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_client-side_log_capture.html) of Worklight, but the Knowledge Center page doesn't reference that URL; in fact, it says that captured data is sent during calls to `init` or `invokeProcedure` instead.

Is it correct that this URL is used to forward captured client-side data? If so, how is the determination made as to when to use it vs. incorporating it into `init` and `invokeProcedure` requests?

Answer (score 0):

`http://myserver.com/myProjectName/apps/services/loguploader` is in fact the endpoint where client logs are uploaded to the Worklight Server.

To send the logs to the server in Hybrid apps you will use

```
WL.Logger.send();
```

For more info in Native iOS and Android you can look at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_data_capture.html